# Jquery Hover Effect Doesn't Work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects

```
html 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<title>Kentucky Appalachian Rural Rehabilitation Network</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#nav li').hover(
function () {
//show submenu
$('ul', this).animate({opacity: "show", }, "slow");

},
function () {
//hide submenu
$('ul', this).fadeOut(250);

}
);


})
</script>
<body><div id="centerColumn">
    <div id="header"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="arav" /><ul id="nav">
<li> <a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Who We Are</a>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Other box</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Menu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Menu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">State Level</a></li>
<li><a href="#">National Level</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Community Level</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li> <a href="#">Research</a></li>

<li> <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
</li>
</ul>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="container">





<div id="footer">
    Footer<a href="#"/>
        </div></div></div></body></html>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin:1em;
padding:0;
height:100%;
background-color:#cccccc;
color:#000000;  
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:1em;
border-style: thin;
}

.img{
    float right;
    padding-left: 3em;
    border:thin black ;

}
#reg{font-family:"Palatino Linotype";


}

#centerColumn {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 50em;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}


#header {
    border-style: thin;
    background-position: center;
    margin: -1em -1em 0 -1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 15.5em;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    background-attachment: scroll;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 

}


#footer {
position:relative;
bottom:0;
margin:4em 0 0 0;
padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
height:5em;
line-height:4em;
text-align:center;
font-size:.8em;
background-color:#cccccc;
border-top:1px solid #999999;
}

/*****remove the list style****/

#nav {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

/*****LI display inline *****/
#nav li {
float:left;
display:block;
width:7em;
background:#0063dc;
position:relative;
z-index:500;
margin:0 1px;
}

/*****parent menu*****/
#nav li a {
display:block;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;

font-weight:700;
height:38px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#696969;
text-align:center;
color:#ffeecc;
}

#nav li a:hover
{
color:#eeeeee;
}

/* style for default selected value */ #nav a.selected {
color:#6699FF;
}
/* submenu */ #nav ul
{
position:absolute;
left:0;
display:none;
margin:0 0 0 -1px;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li
{
width:7em;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;

border-top:1px solid #eeeeee;
}

/* display block will make the link fill the whole area of LI */
 #nav ul a
{
display:block;
height:32px;
padding: 7px 4px;
color:white;
}

#nav ul a:hover
{
text-decoration:none;
padding-left:none;
}
```

Comment: Fundamentally, `fadeIn` *does* work on IE (and @SLaks tells me `opacity: show` works too), so the question has to be why it's having this odd behavior on your page. Can you quote the relevant CSS and HTML?

Comment: Please try to actually format your code and post as small a sample as you possibly can.

Comment: is it not formatted correctly? i have the html and css separated.  i wanted to add all of both of them since it seems that this shouldn't be happening for all intents and purposes.

Comment: have you tried using {opacity: 1} instead of {opacity: "show"} also, opacity doesn't work in IE8 quirks mode :(

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the dangling comma:

```
$('ul', this).animate({opacity: "show", }, "slow");
```

so it is:

```
$('ul', this).animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
```

If it doesn't work then make sure that IE isn't rendering your page in quirks mode or using old rendering engine by starting your HML with something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Comment: While that is correct, it doesn't explain the symptoms.  That would create a syntax error, so it shouldn't show at all.

Comment: @SLaks: That's true. It looks like the $.fx.off was set. Maybe it's being rendered with quirks mode. We don't even know which IE version is it, how the HTML and styles look like, or what other code is being run.

Comment: it's IE 8,  there's no other code being run and it works fine in every other browser, give me a second and i'll quote the html

Comment: @wootwoot: See if you can reproduce this behavior using [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gu4c/).

Comment: yes, it does the same thing in that example that it does on my page.  it just appears, but doesn't fade in.  it works fine in every other browser but IE

Comment: @wootwoot: Strange. What about [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/8gu4c/3/) using fadeIn and fadeOut?

Comment: yes, that does the same thing.  the text just appears doesn't fade in.

Comment: @SLaks: Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: @wootwoot: Did you try adding `<!doctype html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">` in your html as shown in the example above?

Comment: @woot: It looks like a `hasLayout` issue.  Adding CSS `float` or `display:block` fixes it.  I don't have time to look further

Comment: @wootwoot: Check out the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and watch [the talk by Paul Irish](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyM37XKkmKQ) to learn about various tricks to make IE behave like a modern browser. Some of those those tricks might help you here. I'm afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: the whole CSS and HTML is now up if anyone can help with this weird bug.

Comment: @wootwoot: Ok, I have one more idea: Try removing `display:none;` from your CSS for `#nav ul` and add `$('#nav ul').hide();` in your JavaScript. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gu4c/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using .find() instead of  $('ul', this)

example 
 $(this).find('ul').animate(etc...);

here's a link to a js fiddle using an example. It seems to do what you're looking to do, and works in ie8.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nnx5Z/2/

Hope this helps some!